# Changing a branch that is not my own: Push or PR?

Tags: git, pull-request, git-push

Is it good etiquette to issue PR's on remote branches that are not my own, versus just pushing to them?

E.G. my colleague has a feature branch, F1, and I need to make some changes to it.  I think it's more considerate to checkout my own branch that's derived from F1.  I then submit a PR to merge those changes into my colleague's branch.

Alternatively I can just push my changes to F1.  However this is could trample my colleague's work.

I believe submitting a PR from a derived branch is considerate of their branch, but I'm not finding info on best practices in this situation.

Comment: Why not ask your colleague? It's a significantly different scenario if `feature branch` is itself a PR to master or equivalent (i.e. is transient); or if `feature branch` is more akin to a release branch (i.e. long lived and not transient).

Comment: I believe my approach is essentially what you're suggesting.  By submitting a PR, I am considerately asking to modify their branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree with your considerations. Pull down the colleague's branch (F1) and checkout a new branch (F1/myChanges), make your changes then make a pull request and set F1 as the base. This also seems a little cleaner in case whatever you do doesn't work out.

EDIT: this all depends on the specific conventions of your team, of course. When in Rome, git how the Romans git.

Answer (score 1):

You need to collaborate with a colleague?  Follow your organization's work flow.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely create a pull request. Do not push to the branch if you don't own it.